Can a point be a local extrema under constraints if Hessian matrix is indefinite?
So, I know that if I have some open subset which contains stationary point I can use Sylvester's criterion to check if a Hessian matrix is positive-definite. If it's indefinite, that point for sure isn't a local extrema. But, when I have constrained optimization problem I am not guaranteed to have an open subset. When working with constrained optimization (I am mainly working with Lagrange multipliers and have them in mind) we are not usually using Sylvester's criterion, but rather check sign of the second differential (at least in my Calculus course).
Suppose that we have a constrained optimization problem and that we found a stationary point $x_0$ of a function $f(x)$. I was wondering, is it possible for Hessian matrix to be indefinite at a point $x_0$ but for function $f$ to still have a local extrema at $x_0$ under the constraints?

Yeah but it might not be unique locally. Just consider any constant function

I don't really care about uniqueness, I just want an example. Wouldn't Hessian of a constant function be semi-definite?
